# PHP MVC Application loosing path references to jss and css files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

I´m writing my own PHP MVC framework. So, the entry point for bootstrapping is at `myapp/public/index.php`.

There I check the URL passed, as:

```
$url = $_GET["url"];
```

And then I explode the code finding the necessary controller, action and parameters to navigate:

```
    $parts = explode("/", trim($url, "/"));

    if (sizeof($parts) > 0)
    {
        $controller = $parts[0];

        if (sizeof($parts) >= 2)
        {
            $action = $parts[1];
            $parameters = array_slice($parts, 2);
        }
    }
```

From here the code loads and runs the controller and view.

At the controller, I need (after successfull login) redirect to my app main page (called `main/index`). Here is the redirection code:

```
... controller code...
$this->redirect("main", "index");
...
```

And

```
public static function redirect($controller, $method = "index", $args = array())
{
    $location = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . $controller . "/" . $method . "/" . implode("/",$args);

    header("Location: " . $location);
    exit;
}
```

Well, this calls again my `public/index.php`, but from now I loose all of my relative path referentes in the included javascript and css code, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Insted of looking at `myapp/public` it starts looking at `myapp/pubic/main/index` folder, where it natually does not belong to.

Also, `myapp/public/main/index` is not even a valid folder (the controller and action is code is under `application/controllers` folder).

I´m very confused in the way this mechanism of redirecting is working and I can´t find out the solution..

My `.htaccess`, located in `myapp\public`:

```
Options -indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)\.?([a-zA-Z]+)?$ index.php?url=$1&extension=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks for helping....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem with relative links in your css/images etc. Relative paths are resolved by adding the relative path in the parent folder of current page's path.

To resolve, you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/myapp/public/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it's working the way it should. Relative paths will always be relative to the current location. I think absolute paths would be your best bet. You could use a constant for your base directory like BASE_DIR and make all of your content paths relative to that.