# CodeIgniter: CSS: Issue with @import

Tags: css, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, import

I am trying to get some third party CSS templates to work with CodeIgniter.  I think the issue is due to @import statements in the CSS, bit not sure of the exact cause.

Everything works fine when loading just the controller.  But things break when loading anything past the controller.  A trailing slash breaks the CSS.

```
http://example.com/controller = OK
http://example.com/controller/ = Broken
```

Following recommended practices, the directory structure uses the assets directory, like the following:

```
+
├── application
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── images
+
```

mod_rewrite is working correcty.  I can access the files directly.

```
http://example.com/images/picture.jpg = OK
http://example.com/assets/images/picture.jpg = OK
```

.htaccess

```
# Rewrite to use the assets directory for site elements
 RewriteCond $1 ^(css|fonts|images)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /assets/$1 [L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have tried using base_url() in the view.

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But I think the issue is because @import is used in the css files.

```
@import url('font-awesome.min.css');
@import url('mobile.css');
```

***Can anyone offer some insight into this issue?***

Thanks!

Comment: Try something like `url('../css/font-awesome.min.css');` css beaning folder on main directory

Comment: Try not using url. eg. `@import "font-awesome.min.css";`

Comment: Watching the apache logs, the requests were going to /controller/function/assets/etc..
After another search, I found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257968/php-mvc-application-loosing-path-references-to-jss-and-css-files) that solved my issue.
'<head> .. <base href="/base/" /> .. </head>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watching the apache logs, I saw the following:

```
GET /controller/function/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404
```

After another search, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257968/php-mvc-application-loosing-path-references-to-jss-and-css-files) that solved my issue.  Setting the `<base href="/" />` in the `<head>` section of the page.

```
<head>
 <base href="/" />
 ..
 <?php echo link_tag('css/style.css'); ?>
</head>
```

You can see I changed to CI link_tag(), it's working.  *Using the original code should work now too.*